# Pagination in stored procedure without using LIMIT and OFFSET in MySQL.

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have to create one stored procedure for get data with pagination using LIMIT in MySQL. it's working good in my local DB but it's not working on server. So I have try to search in google and getting solution **"Upgrade phpmyadmin version on server"** but it's not possible to do. So any alternate ways for create pagination without LIMIT or OFFSET. ?

Below my code I have tried.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `LazyLoadScope`(IN ClientId INT,IN StartIndex INT,IN Count INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE LowerBound  INT;
DECLARE UpperBound  INT;
DECLARE rownum  INT;
SET LowerBound = ((StartIndex - 1) * Count) + 1;
SET UpperBound = ((StartIndex - 1) * Count) + Count;

SELECT scopeid,scopename,clientid,scope,createddate,ViewDate,IsLocked
FROM scopemaster as sm  inner join clientmaster cm on cm.clientid=sm.clientid
where cm.userid=ClientId order by sm.ViewDate desc LIMIT LowerBound,UpperBound ; 

END
```

Comment: Your version of PHPmyadmin has nothing at all to do with execution of stored procedures on the mysql server. When you say not working what do you mean?

Comment: @e4c5, when i create sp that time give syntax error.

Comment: and that error being?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@kaushik Please try below code.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `LazyLoadScope`(IN ClientId    INT,IN StartIndex INT,IN Count INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE LowerBound INT;
DECLARE UpperBound INT;
DECLARE rownum INT;
SET LowerBound = ((StartIndex - 1) * Count) + 1;
SET UpperBound = ((StartIndex - 1) * Count) + Count;

SELECT scopeid,scopename,clientid,scope,createddate,ViewDate,IsLocked
  from (SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
  from (SELECT   sm.scopeid,sm.scopename,sm.clientid,sm.scope,sm.createddate,sm.ViewDate,sm.Is     Locked
FROM scopemaster as sm
inner join clientmaster cm on cm.clientid=sm.clientid
where cm.userid=ClientId order by sm.ViewDate desc) d, (SELECT @rownum  := 0) r ) m
WHERE rank >= LowerBound and rank <= UpperBound;

END
```